# Trying to understand storing stringAt()

Tags: java, processing

As you can see, I only want to get the character at the position 18 of the String array, which should return a number of type character? My problem is, when I run the first print, it prints the number correctly. Now when I try to store it, it gives me 49 for some reason? I've tried using `NUM = int (name.charAt(18))`, but it doesn't work whatsoever. I'm just trying to actually understand what's going on here.

```java
String name = "Sprites/ships/Ship1.png";
int NUM;
println(name.charAt(18));
NUM = name.charAt(18);
println(NUM);
```

Comment: What do you want to save? The letter like `s` or the ascii code for that letter? Because   I guess the `.charAt()` method will return a char, which is a special primitive type (which can be typecasted to an int).

Comment: I want to save the number 1 in the string? and want it to be saved as an int?

Comment: try to convert the char -> string -> int, because if you go directly from char to int you wont get the representation you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Character.getNumericValue(char)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)).

```java
    String name = "Sprites/ships/Ship1.png";
    int NUM;
    println(name.charAt(18));
    NUM = Character.getNumericValue(name.charAt(18));
    println(NUM)
```